# SOLR sort by IN Query

Tags: solr, solrnet

I was wondering if it is possible to sort by the order that you request documents from SOLR. I am running a **In** based query and would just like SOLR to return them based on the order that I ask.

In (4,2,3,1) should return me documents ordered 4,2,3,1.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [Sorting](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/tutorial.html#Sorting) in solr, to order them by field.

I assume that "In based query" means something like: fetch docs whose `fieldx` has values in (`val1`,`val2`). You can a field as multi-valued field and [facet](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrFacetingOverview) on that field. A facet query is a 'is in' search, out of the box (so to say) and it can do more sophisticated searches too.

---

Edited on OP's query:

**Updating** a document with a multi-valued field in JSON [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateJSON#Update_Commands).  See the line

```
"my_multivalued_field": [ "aaa", "bbb" ]   /* use an array for a multi-valued field */
```

As for doing a **facet query**, check [this](http://www.craftyfella.com/2010/01/faceting-and-multifaceting-syntax-in.html).

You need to do one or more fq statements:

```
&fq=field1:[400 to 500]
&fq=field2:johnson,thompson
```

Also do read up on the fact (in link above) that you need to facet on stored rather than indexed fields.

Comment: yes I mean that. But how would I utilize it to accomplish what I need?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily apply sorting with QueryOptions and field sort (ExtraParams property - I am sorting by savedate field, descending):

```
 var results = _solr.Query(textQuery,
                new QueryOptions
                {
                    Highlight = new HighlightingParameters
                    {
                        Fields = new[] { "*" },
                    },
                    ExtraParams = new Dictionary<string, string>
                    {
                        {"fq", dateQuery},
                        {"sort", "savedate desc"}
                    }
                });
```